# Getting the top layer of 3D perlin Noise

Tags: c++, unreal-4, perlin-noise

I am generating 16x16x64 chunks. Afterwards I apply 3D noise to them. I want the first layer to be all grass blocks and after those I want layers of dirt.

The current problem is that I am getting some dirt blocks in my top layer.
So how do I get the entire top layer of the noise?

```
TArray<int32> heightMap = CalculateNoise();

    for (int32 x = 0; x < 16; ++x)
    {
        for (int32 y = 0; y<16; ++y)
        {
            for (int32 z = 0; z< 64; ++z)
            {
                int32 voxelIndex = x + (y * 16) + (z * (16*16));

                int heightmapValue = heightMap[voxelIndex];

                if (z == 30 + heightmapValue)
                    ChunkIDs[voxelIndex] = 1;
                else if (z == 29 + heightmapValue)
                    ChunkIDs[voxelIndex] = 2;
                else
                    ChunkIDs[voxelIndex] = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A heightmap should be 2 dimensional. Why do you add the z coordinate to the voxelIndex?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the top layer of the heightmap can't you simply do the following:

```
TArray<int32> heightMap = CalculateNoise();

    for (int32 x = 0; x < 16; ++x)
    {
        for (int32 y = 0; y<16; ++y)
        {
            for (int32 z = 0; z< 64; ++z)
            {
                int32 voxelIndex = x + (y * 16) + (z * (16*16));

                int heightmapValue = heightMap[voxelIndex];

                //If the block we're looking at is at the same level as the height map it must be on the surface
                if (z == heightmapValue)
                    ChunkIDs[voxelIndex] = 1;
                else if (z < heightmapValue) //If it's less than that then it's underground
                    ChunkIDs[voxelIndex] = 2;
                else //If it's not below or equal to then it must be air.
                    ChunkIDs[voxelIndex] = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps, Thomas.